# Firebase 'Unhandled Rejection' and 'Can't set headers after they are set' JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, firebase, error-handling, promise, google-cloud-functions

Firstly, please note that I am very very new to JS and coding as a general :)

Desired behaviour:
I have written the following JS HTTPS Firebase function which, which takes in a query parameter `locationId`, it performs a GET API call and saves the response back to Firebase. The code correctly saves the data to Firebase as desired. I have come across similar issues but i'm struggling to adapt those solutions to my specific issue below. From what I see, I'm only sending the response once.

Specific error: The following is the console output

> Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
>
> Unhandled rejection

[image]

My function:

```
exports.doshiiGetMenuForOnboardedVenue = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  // Forbidding PUT requests.
  if (req.method === 'PUT') {
    return res.status(403).send('Forbidden!');
  }

  cors(req, res, () => {

    const locationId = req.query.locationId;

    console.log('locationId', locationId);

    if (locationId){

      console.log('locationId', locationId);

      var token = jwttoken();

      const options = {
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
        };

        const uri = 'https://sandbox.doshii.co/partner/v3/locations/' + locationId + '/menu?lastVersion=:lastVersion&filtered=true'

        axios.get(uri, options)
          .then(response => {

             return admin.database().ref(`/venue-menus/${locationId}/`).set(response.data)
             .then(response => {
               return res.status(200).send(locationId)
             })
             .catch(err => {
               return res.status(500).send({error: err})
             })

          })
          .then(response => {
                    return res.status(200).send(locationId)
            })
          .catch(err => {
            return res.status(500).send({error: err})
          })//end axios

    } else {

      return res.status(500).send({error: 'locationId missing'})

    }//end if-else (!locationId)

  })//end cors

});
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that your code is attempted to send more than one response.  You can call `res.send` only once per function invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By flattening out your nested promises, you can see that your code is performing the following instructions (when the `axios` call doesn't throw an error):

```
admin.database().ref(`/venue-menus/${locationId}/`).set(response.data))
  .then(response => res.status(200).send(locationId))
  .catch(err => res.status(500).send({error: err})
  .then(response => res.status(200).send(locationId)) // this line is always called after either of the above.
  .catch(err => res.status(500).send({error: err})
```

As general practice, unless required, you should not nest promises with their own `then()` and `catch()` handlers as it will lead to bizarre effects like this.

Furthermore, if your code calls for using `//end axios` or `//end cors` messages, you should flatten out your code so it makes sense without those messages.

Adapting your code to "fail fast", correcting your API responses and appropriately hiding error stack traces gives:

```
const cors = require('cors')({
  origin: true,
  methods: ["GET"]
});


exports.doshiiGetMenuForOnboardedVenue = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, (err) => { // note: cors will handle OPTIONS method

    if (err) {
      // note: log full error at ERROR message level
      console.error('Internal CORS error:', err);
      // note: return only generic status message to client
      return res.status(500).json({error: 'Internal Server Error'});
    }

    // Forbidding anything but GET requests.
    if (req.method !== 'GET') {
      // 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
      return res.status(405)
        .set('Allow', 'GET')
        .json({error: 'Not Allowed!'});
    }

    const locationId = req.query.locationId;

    console.log('locationId', locationId);

    if (!locationId) {
      // 400 BAD_REQUEST
      return res.status(400).json({error: 'locationId missing'})
    }

    var token = jwttoken();

    const options = {
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
          'authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
      };

    // note: Don't forget to enable billing for third-party APIs!
    const uri = 'https://sandbox.doshii.co/partner/v3/locations/' + locationId + '/menu?lastVersion=:lastVersion&filtered=true'

    axios.get(uri, options)
      .then(response => admin.database().ref(`/venue-menus/${locationId}/`).set(response.data))
      .then(() => {
        // note: as locationId was already sent by the client, send new/useful
        // information back or nothing but the right status code
        res.status(200).json({ ref: `/venue-menus/${locationId}/` });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // note: log full error at ERROR message level
        console.error('Failed to retrieve/save API data:', err);
        // note: return only message to client
        res.status(500).json({error: err.message || 'Internal Server Error'});
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm getting a `parsing error: Unexpected token ","` at the very last `});` line

Comment: @Roggie Apologies, missed a parenthesis `)` at the end there.

Comment: thanks @samthecodingman but now i'm getting this: `Each then() should return a value or throw `

Comment: @Roggie That's one of your linter's programming style warnings to prevent unexpected `undefined` values in Promise chains, not an actual error with the code as it is above. You can either disable the warning in your linter's configuration or add in explicit `return;` statements at the end of each `then()` and `catch()` handler.

Comment: I've explicitly added the `return` statements, since I'm a beginner I feel that it will help me remember. This has worked perfectly. I really appreciate your assistance, I have learnt a lot from this function alone :)

Comment: If you are a beginner, I'd also recommend the [Firebase Slack](https://firebase.community) as there are plenty of discussions leading to solutions so you can see how other users debug their issues. You might also find [my other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3068190+is%3Aanswer) as helpful. Also don't forget to also upvote the answer if it was of use - accepted answers and upvotes are tracked separately.